# CakePhp Load table content using ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, load, html-table

I have an empty table which I would feed with new rows when I just select an option from my select element

```
<table id="table" align="right" class ="table table-striped table-bordered">
    </table>
```

That's my ajax function , It seems ok but I got no row except the header. and when I print the error I get "parsererror"

```
<script>
      document.getElementById("encaissements").style.visibility = "hidden";


        function loadTransactions (trainer) {
        document.getElementById("encaissements").style.visibility = "visible";
        var trainer = trainer;
        var trHTML = '';
        var headHTML = '<tr><th>' +"Numéro de la facture" + '</th><th>' + 
        "Montant " + '</th><th>' + 
        "Date du réglement  " + '</th><th>' + 
        "Réglée par " + '</th></tr>';

        $('#table').empty(); 
        $('#table').append(headHTML);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/icicpermis/trainers/getTransactions/"+trainer,
            data:  {'trainer': trainer },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
              //console.log(response);
              $.each(response, function(i,value) {
              console.log(value);
              trHTML = '<tr><td>' + value.date + '</td><td>' + value.price + '</td></tr>';
              $('#table').append(trHTML);
              });
              //$('#table').append(trHTML);

             },
            error: function(x, error) {
              console.log(error );
            }
        });
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved The problem by buckling the array value it was an array not a simple json variable

```
success: function(response){

              $.each(response, function(i,value) {
              trHTML= '<tr>';

              trHTML+= '<td>' + indice + '</td>';
              $.each(value, function(j,value2) {
                trHTML+= '<td>' + value2 + '</td>';

              });
               trHTML+= '</tr>';
              $('#table').append(trHTML);
              indice++;
              });

             },
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you perform form submission on selection change event of form fields?? You may use ajax also, all depending on your actual case.

Also, I would add one more suggestion here i.e. use jQuery for DOM selection or manipulation. It will ease your work process and also minimize the lines of code.